Adding Stadia API Jey to QuickMapServices
I have an API key from Stadia Maps. I am trying to add the Stamen maps using QuickMapServices; the map layer appears in the Layer Panel but without any data in the display area. I tried this answer here, but the problem wasn't solved.
The Stamen Maps work fine when I add it using XYZ-Tiles to QGIS via Browser.
Does anyone have a solution?

To add a Stadia Maps API Key in the URL, you'll need to name the query string argument api_key (note the underscore; the answer related to ThunderForest uses apikey instead). Here's the documentation for reference: Stadia Maps Authentication Docs.
Here's a screenshot of what my QuickMapServices config looks like:


Thank you for your help
